# How can I make my class variable assignment dynamic?

Tags: php, class, constants, declaration

In the following code, I want to assign an `$settings`'s key, `help` to a constant class variable value, `$To_default`. However, I am told `Constant expression contains invalid operations`. Is there any way I can get around this?

```php
class EmailClass extends PluginBase {

  private $To_default = 'scrollout@stackoverflow.com';

  protected $settings = array(
    'To'=>array(
      'type'=>'text',
      'label'=>'To',
      'help'=>$this->To_default, // Constant expression contains invalid operations
    ),
  );
```

I've tried declaring `$To_default` in various ways including `private const $To_default`, `static private $To_default`, etc. but none worked. `$settings` is not static, as you can see, so I don't understand why this is a problem.

Comment: You can't use variables in the default value of a class variable.

Comment: Why not make  `$To_default` a constant?

Comment: @Barmar I've mentioned trying that. See the first sentence beneath my code snippet.

Comment: The constant works, you got the syntax wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know deep technical explanation for this but I think this is because normally you initialize properties in the constructor, like so:

```
class EmailClass 
{
private $To_default = 'scrollout@stackoverflow.com'; // not a constant, so better throw it into constructor too
protected $settings;

public function __construct() {
    $this->settings = array(
    'To'=>array(
    'type'=>'text',
    'label'=>'To',
    'help'=>$this->To_default
    )
    );
}
}
```

Analogical I don't know why: 'if isset(expression)' doesn't work but it doesn't have to.  There's a better solution: 'if(expression)'. This is just how we do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify a default value that refers to another class property ($settings is an array that tries to read $To_default).

My recommendation is that $settings can be the result of a getter method, for example getSettings, and inside of it you can build an array and return it.

By doing do this, you can also decide to override the $To_default value with a setTo method.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

class EmailClass extends PluginBase {
    private string $toDefault = '';

    /**
     * @param string $toDefault
     */
    public function __construct( string $toDefault = 'scrollout@stackoverflow.com' ) {
        $this->toDefault = $toDefault;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $toDefault
     */
    public function setToDefault( string $toDefault ): void
    {
        $this->toDefault = $toDefault;
    }

    public function getSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'TO' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'To',
                'help' => $this->toDefault,
            ]
        ];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class constant rather than a variable for the default.

Constants don't begin with `$`, that's the problem you had when you tried this.

```
class EmailClass extends PluginBase {

  private const TO_DEFAULT = 'scrollout@stackoverflow.com';

  protected $settings = array(
    'To'=>array(
      'type'=>'text',
      'label'=>'To',
      'help'=>self::TO_DEFAULT, // Constant expression contains invalid operations
    ),
  );
}
```